# Mandrill: merge_vars not working

Tags: php, json, email, mandrill, mailmerge

I'm working on sending diffenrent links to user emails via Mandrill 'merge_vars' but it is not working. Relevant parts from API log:

```
"message": {
    "preserve_recipients": false,
    "auto_text": false,
    "auto_html": false,
    "to": [
        {
            "email": "kajacx10@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "html": "... link: *|REFUSELINK|* ...",
    "text": "... link: *|REFUSELINK|* ...",
    "merge": true,
    "merge_language": "mailchimp",
    "merge_vars": [
        {
            "recipient": "kajacx10@gmail.com",
            "vars": [
                {
                    "name": "refuselink",
                    "content": "http://myLink.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"key": "myKey"
```

I receive the email correctly, but I see the original `*|REFUSELINK|*` instead of the desired replacement. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ups, it's `rcpt`, not `recipient`:

```
"merge_vars": [
    {
        "rcpt": "kajacx10@gmail.com", /* <-- here */
        "vars": [
            {
                "name": "refuselink",
                "content": "http://myLink.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```